# Airflow > S3 Connection fails on workers

Tags: airflow

I've created an 'S3' type connection in Airflow (1.7), via the administrative interface, and have validated that it works on the box that hosts Airflow itself. The connection does not work, however, on any of the workers, running on separate boxes.

I'm testing the connection via the following process:

```
# Launch the Python shell
/usr/local/bin/python2.7   

# Issue the following
import airflow  
s3 = airflow.hooks.S3Hook('remote_log_s3') 
s3.load_string('test', airflow.conf.get('core', 'remote_base_log_folder'))
```

On a worker, the above will return the following:

`boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`

On the box hosting Airflow itself, the string will be loaded to the specified S3 location as expected.

I've attempted to resolve the issue by restarting the Airflow workers but this had no effect. I'm looking for any suggestions on steps that may need to be taken to enable the workers to utilize the connection.

Comment: If you check the airflow connection called 'remote_log_s3' though the web interface is the 'aws_access_key_id' and 'aws_secret_access_key' in the extra JSON part of the connection properties? Otherwise if you see something like 's3_config_file' in there instead then the reason could be that the config file that stores the credentials probably only lives on your airflow master machine and needs to be put in the same location on the workers.

Comment: @SimonD, yes. I've used the approach of specifying the access key id and secret key right in the "Extra" field. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your AWS setup is not restricting access to these S3 buckets to particular IP addresses? One way to find out would be to log into the worker machine and use the AWS CLI to list the contents of the bucket.

Comment: @SimonD - Thanks for the additional suggestion. It seems that the issue was that we needed to copy the airflow.cfg, which is where `remote_base_log_folder ` is defined, to the worker nodes themselves.